# Call HTTP function get empty string but success get content

Tags: nativescript

I'm new in JavaScript Nativescript. I trying do get result using HTTP and I success get result using alert, but when I call this function it will return empty string. I try other method but the result also same. Isn't I write wrong code?

model-view:

```
    function GetResult(url) {
            var viewModel = new ObservableArray([]);

            viewModel.abc = function() {

                 http.getString(url).then(function (response) {
                      return response;
                 }, function (e) {
                      return e;
                });

             };

             return viewModel
        }
module.exports = GetResult;
```

pageLoad JS :

```
var List = new viewModel("http://localhost/test/");
function onPageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    dialogs.alert(List.abc());
    page.bindingContext = load;
}
exports.onPageLoaded = onPageLoaded;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't wrong. When you call the function directly, it will only return variable viewModel. The http request you sent is asynchronous and as soon as it finishes it'll return the response to the callback function:

```
          function (response) {
                  return response;
         }
```

You're not doing anything wrong, you're just not thinking asynchronously. Don't worry, you'll eventually get used to it.

Comment: viewModel.abc = function() {
         return http.getString(url).then(function (response) {
                          return response;
                     }, function (e) {
                          return e;
           }).then(function(data){
               return data;
           });
     };

Isn't callback is using then function ?

Comment: the callback is the function you provided as the first parameter in the .then() function